# divs anidados en CSS

Tags: css

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Modelo Cajas</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #contenedor{
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border:solid 2px;

    }
    #interno{
        height: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        border: dashed 10px red;
    }
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contenedor">
        <div id="interno"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No entiendo por qué el div "interno" sobrepasa en altura al div "contenedor".
Sospecho que puede ser por la propiedad height pero no entiendo el por qué se produce este efecto.
Gracias

Comment: Se entendería mejor si en el ejemplo le quitas el fondo azul al `div` hijo, me ha costado ver el borde del otro `div` por debajo

Comment: He quitado el color de fondo.
Gracias

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tiene que ver con la propiedad `box-sizing`. Por defecto, esta definida en `content-box`, lo que significa, que si asignas `width` y `height`, esto se asignara al contenido sin tener en cuenta paddings y borders. Lo que quiere decir que la altura de tu "caja" sera

> 100% + padding + border = altura total

.

Si quieres que esto no ocurra, asigna `border-box` a la propiedad `box-sizing: border-box;`. Esto hará que la altura y width que definas, incluya el borde y padding. Así que sera de la siguiente manera;

> contenido + padding + border = 100% = altura total

```
#interno{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 20px;
    border: dashed 10px red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> La propiedad box-sizing puede contener 3 valores: **content box**, **padding
>   box**, **border box**.

El valor por defecto es **content box**. Esto es muy importante ya que altera la forma en que calculas tanto el ancho como el alto de tus cajas.

---

La regla es simple. Si usas content box el ancho de tus cajas sera: margen izquierdo + borde izquierdo + padding izquierdo + ancho + padding derecho + borde derecho + margen derecho. La misma regla aplicaria para el alto.

---

Si usas padding box, no tienes que recalcular el ancho de tus cajas si usas padding, mas sin embargo si lo debes hacer cuando usas bordes y margenes.

---

Por ultimo en border box solo tendriamos que estar al tanto de los margenes. En la actualidad se utiliza como buena practica border-box, ya que te evita recalcular el tamaño de tus cajas si añades las propiedades antes mencionadas.